# Chaning text in a list and preserving attributes

Tags: javascript

When `List Item 1` is changed into `Hello`, `li` looses all the other attributes. How to change the text without modifying its attributes?

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li')
items[0].innerHTML = 'Hello'


console.log(items[0]);
```

```html
            <ul class="collection">
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item 1
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li> 
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item 2
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li> 
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item 3
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: Set innerText instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @CharlesBamford unfortunately `<i>` both with `innerHTML` or `innerTEXT` get lost. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `innerHTML` or `innerText` you will replace all the content of that element. Your `<li>` element contains your text and the additional `<a>` element. So if you set the `innerHTML` or the `innerText` on the element the `<a>` element is also overwritten.

If it is possible you may wrap the text of all `<li>` elements in a `<span>` element.

```
<li class="collection-item">
    <span>List Item 1</span>
    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

So you need to change your JavaScript code to select the `span` instead.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li > span')
items[0].innerHTML = 'Hello'
```

As already mentioned in the comments you might want to use `innerText` if the text you want to set contains angle bracketes `<>` because they will be interpreted as HTML tags instead of plain text which you might not want.

```
items[0].innerText = 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` is the correct attribute, so:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
items[0].innerText = 'Hello';
console.log(items[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think understand your problem now. If you only want to replace the text, without losing the link, you could do something like this:

```js
// Get the elements on the page that we care about.
const remove = document.querySelector("a");
const listItem = document.querySelector("li");
  
remove.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Replace the contents of the list item. This includes the
  // anchor.
  listItem.innerText = ":(";
    
  // Add the anchor back on to the list item.
  listItem.appendChild(remove);
});
```

```html
<li>
  Happy days
  <a>Remove it</a>
</li>
```

Addendum: As a general rule it's better to use innerText when modifying the dom instead of innerHTML, if your users have any way to set the text that is being used, innerHTML would allow them to add a script tag, and then your site's security is over.